# Finding the root of a function by Bisection Method

Tags: c++, binary-search, numerical-methods

The program has to look for a root in an interval `[a,b]`. The root should be declared with a certain accuracy `eps`. I.e it should look for a part-interval in `[a,b]`, which has the length of `eps`.

The bisection algorithm should be:

1. Save the interval boundaries
2. Look if `[a,b]` has a root. (original given interval)
3. look if `a-b < eps`. If yes, part-interval found.
4. If no, divide `[a,b]` in half and continue with point 2. etc.

(We can assume that there is already a root in the given original interval `[a,b]`)

I've tested it with following functions:

`log x + 2`

`x*x*x`

`-3.*x*x + x + 2.`

Are there any improvements possible or did I make a big mistake?

Bisection.cpp

```
#include "Bisection.hpp"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


void bisection(std::vector<double>& interval, double eps) {
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;

  a = interval[0];
  b = interval[1];

  if (b - a < eps) // interval already 'found'
  {
    return;
  }

  do
  {
    c = (a + b) / 2.0;

    if (f(c) == 0)
    {
      a = c;
      b = c; 
    }
    else 
    {
      if (f(a) * f(c) > 0)
      {
        a = c;
      }
      else
      {
        b = c;
      }                  
    }


  } while (f(c) != 0 || b - a > eps);

  /*found part-interval with the length of < eps*/
  interval[0] = a;
  interval[1] = b;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `while (f(c) != 0 || b - a > eps)` rather than `while (f(c) != 0 && b - a > eps)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Headers and namespaces

- The `<cmath>` header is referenced, but never used; it can be removed.
- If we're to use `std::vector`, we require

  ```
  #include <vector>
  ```
- This is a danger sign:

  ```
  using namespace std;
  ```

  Bringing all names in from a namespace is problematic; `namespace std` particularly so. See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).  Happily, we can just delete this line.

## Function interface

- As [Zeta's answer](/a/179518) says, a vector is overkill to represent a numeric range.
- By preference, functions arguments should be inputs, and the output should be as a return value, something like:

  ```
  double find_root(double min, double max, double epsilon);
  ```

  It's also better to pass the function as an argument, rather than via the (undeclared) global `f`:

  ```
  double find_root(std::function<double(double)> f,
                   double min, double max, double epsilon);
  ```

  (You could pass a function pointer instead, but `std::function` is more general, and ought to have no overhead when wrapping a function pointer).

If the caller actually needs the lower and upper bounds of the improved range, you could return both values by using a suitable compound type.  Choose from `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, `std::array` - or define your own "interval" type (which you could also use as the input range).

## Implementation

- Instead of a `do`-`while` preceded by the same test, we could flip it into `while`-`do`:

  ```
  while (min + epsilon < max) { ... }
  ```
- We can avoid any risk of overflow in computing the midpoint if we divide first, then add:

  ```
   auto mid = 0.5 * min + 0.5 * max;
  ```

  If we want to move towards linear interpolation, we'd want

  ```
  auto mid = (min * f_max - max * f_min) / (f_max - f_min)
  ```

  and then move the furthest bound to the mid.
- We're calling `f()` repeatedly - this may be inefficient if it is a weighty computation.  We probably want to keep a record of `f(min)`, `f(max)` and `f(mid)`, and only update as we narrow the range.
- Instead of multiplying two values to determine whether they have the same sign, it's more efficient to obtain each sign as a boolean, and compare those:

  ```
  if (f(min) * f(mid) > 0) // expensive
  if ((f(min) < 0) == (f(mid) < 0)) // cheaper
  ```
- There's little point ever comparing equality of a floating-point value; simply omit those tests and allow the function to converge.

## The `main()` function

- No `main()` was supplied, but it was hinted at.

---

## Improved code

```
#include <functional>

double find_root(std::function<double(double)> f,
                 double min, double max, double epsilon)
{
    auto f_min = f(min);
    while (min + epsilon < max) {
        auto const mid = 0.5 * min + 0.5 * max;
        auto const f_mid = f(mid);

        if ((f_min < 0) == (f_mid < 0)) {
            min = mid;
            f_min = f_mid;
        } else {
            max = mid;
        }
    }

    return min;
}

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "log x + 2: "
              << find_root([](double x) { return std::log(x) + 2; }, 0.001, 1.0, 1e-7)
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x*x*x: "
              << find_root([](double x) { return x*x*x; }, -0.1, 1.0, 1e-11)
              << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-3.*x*x + x + 2.: "
              << find_root([](double x) { return -3.*x*x + x + 2.; }, -5, 5, 1e-7)
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think passing two `double&` arguments is better than forcing the user to manually calculate the interval's upper bound with `min + espsilon` (even though the actual interval may be smaller).

Comment: If the caller actually needs a range as result, rather than a "near enough" value, I think it's better to return the range (as a Standard Library pair/tuple/array or as a user-defined type).  In/out arguments always make code harder to read.

Answer (score 8):

A `std::vector<T> vec` is an arbitrary collection of `T`s. `vec` might contain none, one or many elements. However, you want to model an interval, which consists of *exactly two elements*. A `std::vector<T>` therefore isn't the correct container for an interval.

You could use `std::pair<double, double>` instead, or just write your own variant:

```
struct interval_type {
    double lower_bound;
    double upper_bound;
};
```

Next, try to initialize the variables instead of just declaring them. While we're at it, try to come up with better names, e.g. instead of

```
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;

  a = interval[0];
  b = interval[1];
```

write

```
  double lower = interval.lower_bound; // if you use the struct from above
  double upper = interval.upper_bound;
```

`c`'s scope is too large, by the way. It's just necessary inside the loop, so we can limit its life time, but we need to `break` in this case:

```
  do
  {
    const double midpoint = (lower + upper) / 2.0;

    if (f(midpoint) == 0)
    {
      a = midpoint;
      b = midpoint; 
      break;
    }
    else 
    {
      if (f(lower) * f(midpoint) > 0)
      {
        lower = midpoint;
      }
      else
      {
        upper = midpoint;
      }                  
    }
  } while (upper - lower > eps);
```

Other than that, the test `f(value) == 0` is usually too strict, since floating point arithmetic can be a finicky beast. `std::abs(f(value)) <= some_eps` works well enough most of the times.

Other than that, I suggest you to allow other functions than a fixed `f`. Something along

```
template <typename F>
interval_type bisection(F && f, interval_type interval, double eps = 1e-8){

}
```

comes to mind. As you can see, there is no reason to change the `interval` in place. Just return a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some additional test cases on the interval [0.0, 1.0] with epsilon = 0.1:

1. f(x) = (x - 0.2) * (x - 0.2)
2. f(x) = 1e-200 * (x - 0.8) + 1e-202
3. f(x) = x

Function #1 has a root within the interval, but the OP function `bisection()` fails because it does not check for a precondition of the bisection algorithm, namely that the function being evaluated is not non-zero and opposite signs at the interval endpoints.  If the preconditions are not met, either return a separate error code / error condition, or return NAN for the returned containing end points.

Function #2 has a root at 0.8, but the OP function `bisection()` erroneously reports it as being in the interval [0.0, 0.0625] because the expression `f(a) * f(b)` is equal to 0 due to floating point underflow.

Function #3 has a root at 0.0, the end point.  Note that using a condition of `(f(a) < 0.0) == (f(b) < 0.0)` fails this test case if checking the endpoints for zero function values is not done before entering the loop.

Unless you know the `bisection()` function will be used only in rather protected circumstances, it is a good idea to check its input parameters early in the function.  Here is one example that passes the function f as a parameter, checks parameters for validity before continuing, avoids some other overflow exposures, avoids redundant calls to evaluate f (in case they are expensive) and returns an interval of length zero if an exact zero is found:

```
#include <cmath>

void bisection(double (*f)(double), double& lower, double& upper, double epsilon) {
  double f_lower;
  double f_upper;


  if (!(std::isfinite(lower) && std::isfinite(upper) && epsilon > 0.0 && lower <= upper))
  {
    lower = upper = NAN;
    return;
  }
  f_lower = f(lower);
  f_upper = f(upper);
  if (!(f_lower <= 0.0 && f_upper >= 0.0 || f_lower >= 0.0 && f_upper <= 0.0))
  {
    lower = upper = NAN;
    return;
  }

  if (f_lower == 0) {
    upper = lower;
  }
  if (f_upper == 0) {
    lower = upper;
  }

  while (lower + epsilon < upper)
  {
    double mid = lower * 0.5 + upper * 0.5;
    double f_mid = f(mid);

    if (f_mid == 0)
    {
      lower = mid;
      upper = mid; 
    }
    else 
    {
      if (f_lower > 0.0 && f_mid > 0.0 || f_lower < 0.0 && f_mid < 0.0)
      {
        lower = mid;
        f_lower = f_mid;
      }
      else
      {
        upper = mid;
      }                  
    }
  }
}
```